# Spring Boot and PowerMockito integration

Tags: spring-boot, powermock, powermockito

Im trying to use PowerMockito in my Spring Boot project and running into a weird issue. I'm using PowerMockito to mock a number of static methods in a 3rd party library.

My test class follows the pattern,

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(fullyQualifiedNames = "io.intercom.api.*")
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.*.*", "com.sun.*", "org.xml.*", "com.intellij.*"})
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@Slf4j
public class ServiceAITest extends AbstractITest {
}
```

Abstract test class,

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@DirtiesContext
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@Slf4j
public abstract class AbstractITest {
}
```

This works fine and I can mock the static methods e.t.c but the moment I introduce a second test class I get the following error,

```
2019-02-27 20:00:44.428  WARN [test-events-service,,,] 9406 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testEventsServiceTestConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.cassandra.db:type=DynamicEndpointSnitch
2019-02-27 20:00:44.461 ERROR [test-events-service,,,] 9406 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testEventsServiceTestConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.cassandra.db:type=DynamicEndpointSnitch
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1623)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:121)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner$2.call(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:149)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner$2.call(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:141)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.withContextClassLoader(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:132)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.run(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:141)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.cassandra.db:type=DynamicEndpointSnitch
    at org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch.registerMBean(DynamicEndpointSnitch.java:151)
    at org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch.<init>(DynamicEndpointSnitch.java:109)
    at org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch.<init>(DynamicEndpointSnitch.java:79)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.createEndpointSnitch(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applySnitch(DatabaseDescriptor.java:963)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyAll(DatabaseDescriptor.java:318)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.daemonInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:142)
    at org.cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra(EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.java:137)
    at org.cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra(EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.java:102)
    at org.cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra(EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.java:81)
    at org.cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra(EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.java:73)
    at org.cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra(EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.java:69)
    at co.demo.testeventsservice.configuration.TestEventsServiceTestConfiguration.startCassandra(TestEventsServiceTestConfiguration.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.cassandra.db:type=DynamicEndpointSnitch
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch.registerMBean(DynamicEndpointSnitch.java:147)
    ... 72 common frames omitted
```

My test configuration class looks like the following which loads an embedded Cassandra,

```
@TestConfiguration
@Slf4j
public class TestEventsServiceTestConfiguration {

    public TestEventsServiceTestConfiguration() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void startCassandra() throws InterruptedException, IOException, TTransportException {
        EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra();
        log.info("Successfully started Embedded Cassandra server.");
    }
}
```

To me it looks like its trying to add an already existing `MBean`. Can someone shed some light on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Revisited the `PowerMockIgnore` annotation and refactored it to the following,

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*", "javax.security.*", "org.cassandraunit.*", "org.apache.cassandra.*", "com.intellij.*"})
```

This seems to solve the Embedded Cassandra issue when integrating with PowerMockito.